# UNIX script is unresponsive?

Tags: bash, shell

This is my remove script. Not sure why my project is unresponsive, It doesn't give an error, it just doesn't do anything when I type "sh remove filename" into the command line. I have to hit CTRL C to exit.  Ignore the line numbers. I posted my code and what I have to do below:

> - Create script named remove
> - Create a recycle bin in $HOME/deleted in your script
> - For any file to be deleted, it will be a command line argument and the script should executed as follows: sh remove fileName.
> - The script must test for the same error conditions as the rm command and display the same error messages as the rm command
> - The filenames in the recycle bin should be in the following format: filename_inode

```
    #!/bin/bash
    2 sh remove "filename"
    3 function directory(){
    4 #Makes the deleted directory
    5
    6 if [ ! -d ~/deleted ]
    7     then
    8        mkdir ~/deleted
    9 fi
    16}
    17 function movefile(){
    18 #moving files to recycle bin
    19 mv $l ~/deleted/$l
    20 echo "File moved to recycle bin "
    21 }
    22
    23
    24 function error_conditions(){
    25 #prints error messages
    26 if [ ! -f ~/project ]
    27     then
    28         echo "sh: remove: cannot remove '$filename': no such file or directory"
    29 elif [ ! -d ~/project ]
    31     then
    32        echo "sh remove: cannot remove '$filename': is a directory"
    33 else
    34   echo "sh remove: missing operand"
   35  fi
   37 }
   38
   40 function delete_file(){
   41 #gets inode for filename
   42 inode=$(stat -c%i $filename)
   43 filename=$1
   44 pwd=$(readlink -e$filename)
   45 if $interactive
   46     then
            if $verbose = true ]
   47     read -p "Are you sure you want to delete $filename?" i_input
   48         if [ $i_input = "y" ] || [ $i_input = "Y" }
   49             then
   50             mv $filename ~/delete/${filename}_$inode
   51         fi
   52 fi
   53 }
   54 directory 
   55 error_conditions $*
   56 delete_file $*
   57 move_file $*
```

Comment: Is this the `remove` script?  In that case, it is calling itself recursively on the first line (well, line 2). Remove `sh remove "filename"` from that line.

Comment: This is the remove script. If I remove "sh remove filename", how would I use sh remove filename on the command to act as the same as the rm command?

Comment: I don't understand. To run the script, you would make it executable and then use `./remove whateverfile`.  The script should not call itself recursively. If you want to have it execute whenever `rm` is used, you would probably wrap it in an alias or shell function that you declare in your shell's startup files. But that's a later issue, you have a number of other issues in the code that you will have to deal with first.

Comment: The goal of this whole thing is to imitate the rm command. I want to have "sh remove filename" act the exact same as "rm filename". So if I do "sh remove file1" in the command line, it will do the exact same thing as if i typed "rm file1" in the command line. Can you tell me what other issues I have in my code?

Comment: No, you want a script that acts like `mv`. A script that acts like `rm` would actually remove files. You want your script to _move_ files. In any case, the script should not need to _call itself_.

Comment: Other issues: `~deleted` will try to access the home directory of a user called `deleted`. The `error_conditions` does not look at `$filename`.  `$filename` is not double quoted, so the script won't handle filenames with spaces, for example. You pass `$*` (unquoted, should be `"$@"`) to shell functions that does not use their arguments. You have function called `movefile`, but call `move_file`. You seem to call both `delete_file` and `move_file` and they both move the file (although `movefile` uses the unset variable `$l`). There's a `[` missing in a test. `$interactive` seems to be unset.

Comment: You also have  problem with the function `directory`. There is no closing `}` in the function definition. You are also calling the function with the parameters `$*` but the function itself does nothing with the arguments.

Comment: I'm confused on what specific changes I should make. For error_conditions, I removed the single quotes around $filename. I fixed the syntax error at line 50 to "~/delete" instead of "~deleted". For the directory function, I removed the $* from my main function and added a closing } below the fi. I'm still not sure how to make the sh remove filename command like it asks. Would an alias work? And is that all the errors?

Comment: You don't need to use an alias, nor do you even need to technically mark the file as executable.  When you call `sh remove filename` from the terminal, you are running the shell interpreter `sh` and passing it the file you want it to run along with any arguments.  `sh` then runs this command and passes your arguments into it.  (though it could be marked executable in order to more easily do `./remove fileName` anyway).

Additionally, what Kusalananda meant is that your `error_conditions` isn't even checking for the file you pass, it's just checking if ~/project exists.

Comment: So, you don't need to "make" the command at all, just name your script file "remove" and get rid of line 2.  Calling `sh remove` is what tells the shell to run that file.

Comment: In fact, you should probably paste the script into https://shellcheck.net/ and fix the more obvious errors first.

Comment: Don't deface your question. It invalidates the comments and the given answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the code in your question is in a file called `remove`, line 2 is causing your infinite loop in the `remove` script. Basically, BASH scripts run each line as a command from top to bottom. When you try to run the `remove` script, it will reach line 2 (`sh remove "filename"`) and try to run another instance of `remove`. That new instance tries to run a third instance of `remove` and so forth.

Long story short, remove or comment out line 2:

```
# sh remove "filename"
```

That said, be careful when writing a file to delete files. You don't want to make a mistake and delete something that shouldn't be deleted. I didn't go through the rest of the script. I would comment out lines that actually move files on the first few test runs at the very least.

Comment: Ideally, a script is tested after _each single statement added to it_.  That way, you know why it breaks when it breaks (it's because of the last statement you added to it).